# Remove Selected Row Without Destroying Hidden Formulas

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Would anyone be able to provide some direction on how best I would be able to write a code that will allow me to remove the selected row within a table that I have? Within my table are hidden formulas, links to other cells & sheets as well as hidden columns.
This is the code that I am currently tinkering with that removes the row however when running the code the table formulas return a `#REF!` error. Pretty much a novice, so any help and guidance is greatly appreciated! :)

```
Sub Remove_Selected_Data()

    ' This subroutine clears the Selected Data from the row in the expenses and income table
    ' which is currently selected

    Dim iSelectedRow As Integer
    Dim sAnswer As String
    Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2020_Data")
    Set lo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2020_Data").ListObjects("Table1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    iSelectedRow = ActiveCell.Row

    ' Check if selected row is a valid row to delete
    If iSelectedRow = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a row within the Table!", vbExclamation, "Test1"
        Exit Sub

    ElseIf iSelectedRow > lo.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a row within the Table!", vbExclamation, "Test2"
        Exit Sub

    End If

    ' Check if you really want to clear all data
    sAnswer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear the Selected data?" & vbNewLine & _
        "Click Yes to continue", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Test3")

    If sAnswer = vbYes Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ws.Rows(iSelectedRow).Delete
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some of the formulas in the cell inside the table is referencing the previous rows. Try filling down the formulas in the error column after row removal using .Filldown or something.